# About GCP PubSub Push subscriber validating jwt

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

PubSub docs says that "For high volume push requests, it would save some network overhead if you verify the tokens offline by downloading Google's Public Cert and decode them using the `google.auth.jwt` module".
I'm confused that how and where to downloading Google's Public Cert?

Answer (score 1):

You can find them in [this section](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token)